# SQL select latest entry in the category among visible

Tags: sql

I have an sql table:

```
DATE  USER     FLAGGED    COMMAND   
1     Alice    0          sudo gparted   
2     Bob      1          sudo   
3     Bob      0          mv   
4     Alice    1          sudo rm -rf    
5     Charlie  1          sudo chown
```

I want to select last flagged action of a user

```
DATE  USER     FLAGGED    COMMAND    
2     Bob      1          sudo    
4     Alice    1          sudo rm -rf   
5     Charlie  1          sudo chown
```

I tried

```
select DATE, USER, REQUEST
from
(

select DATE, USER, REQUEST, FLAGGED
row_number() over(partition by USER order by date desc) rn
from USERDATA
) src
where rn = 1 and FLAGGED = 1
```

but it omites Bob. How can I. What is the correct way to add "FLAGGED = 1" to SQL request?

Comment: it omites Bob because the row where flagged = 1 it's the second for that user if you order by date desc

Comment: `(partition by USER order by date desc,flagged desc) rn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you first select latest entries for user and then drop those that are not flagged. Instead you should first select all entries that are FLAGGED and then find the most recent of them. This code should work.

```
 select DATE, USER, REQUEST
 from
  (
    select DATE, USER, REQUEST, FLAGGED 
   row_number() over(partition by USER order by DATE desc) rn
    from USERDATA WHERE FLAGGED = 1  
  ) src
 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the flagged condition to the sub-query, so only the rows with flagged=1 will be retrieved and you can select the latest one with rn=1 condition.

```
select DATE, USER, REQUEST
from
(
select DATE, USER, REQUEST, FLAGGED,
row_number() over(partition by USER order by date desc) rn
from USERDATA
where flagged = 1
) src
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a generic `MAX` query:

```
select DATE, USER, REQUEST
from USERDATA
WHERE (date, user) IN (
  select MAX(DATE) as date, USER
  from USERDATA
  where flagged = 1
  group by user
) 
AND flagged = 1
```

However, please be aware that if there are two user entries with the same date which is the MAX, this may return duplicated... you can avoid this by using a MIN or MAX on the outer SELECT.